# Serial communication between python + arduino and parsing string

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, indexof

I'm trying to send a set of `[x, y] coordinates` from python to arduino in order to control servo motors on a robot drivetrain. I'm taking the approach of sending a string in the format `"x,y"`. On the arduino side, I'm trying to parse this string to get the x and y substrings. However the `indexOf` function doesn't return the proper index. Here is my code:

```
arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=.1)

def write_read(x):
    arduino.write(bytes(x, 'utf-8'))
    time.sleep(0.05)
    data = arduino.readline()
    return data

for coordinate in coordinates:
    c = str(coordinate[0]) + ", " + str(coordinate[1])
    print(write_read(c))
```

```
#include <Servo.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(1);
}

void loop() {
  while (!Serial.available());
  String coordinates = "" + Serial.readString();
//  Serial.print(coordinates); //this prints normally as the string value
  int i = coordinates.indexOf(',');
  Serial.print(i);
}
```

When I send something like `"-9.45, -16.3"`. The output is `b'-1-1-1-1-10-1-1-1-1-1-1'`. I'm not sure what's going on here or how to get the actual index (in this case it would be 5).

Comment: `Serial.setTimeout(1);` That's a pretty small amount of time. Try a larger value there. The default is 1000.

Comment: Awesome that did the trick. I set it to 100 and it works now, thanks!